# Wordpress HTTPS mode strange behavior

Tags: wordpress, nginx, fpm

I'm running Wordpress on nginx+fpm (port 80) behind another Nginx with SSL set up and such.
I have some background with doing this things right and Wordpress is working fine delivering site, letting into wp-admin etc. However, I've stumbled into the fact that 'index.php' of WP does not honor HTTPS=on mode for some reason.

Testing stand:
Wordpress set to deliver pages on https://example.com/info/ URL from IP 10.130.0.4 behind proxy.

1.

```
# curl -I -H "Host: example.com" -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" http://10.130.0.4/wp-login.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 27 Jan 2021 18:29:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Set-Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/info/; secure
Set-Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/; secure
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

2. 

```
# curl -I -H "Host: example.com" -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" http://10.130.0.4/info/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 27 Jan 2021 18:32:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Link: <https://example.com/info/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
```

3. 

```
# curl -I -H "Host: example.com" -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" http://10.130.0.4/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 27 Jan 2021 18:35:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Link: <https://example.com/info/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
```

And number 4 that makes me almost literally bump my head against the table is:

```
# curl -I -H "Host: example.com" -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" http://10.130.0.4/index.php
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 27 Jan 2021 18:39:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Redirect-By: WordPress
Location: https://example.com/
```

Nginx is set up using the most widespread gist for it:

```
        location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
            # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass php;
            #The following parameter can be also included in fastcgi_params file
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     https;
            fastcgi_param  HTTPS              on;
            fastcgi_param  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }
```

If I am missing anything obvious here, please point me to it.
Again, WP is working wholly fine but AIOSEO plugin is trying to deliver robots.txt via 'http://10.130.0.4/index.php?aioseo_robots_path=root' and gets redirected to https://example.com which is different (static) site.

Comment: 4. has `X-Redirect-By: WordPress` ... 

Comment: I know, that's what my question is all about. Can you please elaborate what is so funny here?